# Does react-router support relative links?

Tags: url, reactjs

I'm on this url:

```
/path1/path2
```

Then:

```
<Link to="path2/path3" />
```

With this code the address in the address bar is changed to:

```
/path1/path2/path3
```

It seems to have worked: it has gone to the last `/` and added the new path to that. But, in fact, while it changes the url in the address bar no navigation happens.

It looks like Links have to be given absolute urls?

Comment: Try `<Link to="path3">`  or `<Link to="path3" />` , Since you are already on path2, you just need to go one layer below, assuming path3 is next layer below to path2

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a `link` tag instead of `a` ? `link` is for stylesheets and are used in headers - not for clickable links. There's no `to` attribute to it also.

Comment: @PinkTurtle You're thinking of the wrong `Link`. This is the `<Link />` component provided by react-router https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/IndexRoutes.md#index-links

Comment: Thanks Anil_M. Same problem: even though we end up with what looks like the correct path in the browser address bar the route is not matched by the router unless it starts with '/'. The example in the changelog is an absolute url so I'm tending to think that it requires absolute paths.

Comment: You can see there was actually a [really long discussion](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/2172) about this on GitHub.

Answer (score 35):

in react-router v4 relative paths are supported. The `history` library resolves relative paths 'just like a browser would' so that a

```
<Link to="two" />
```

or a

```
history.push({ pathname: '..', search: 'foo=bar' });
```

at the url `site.com/path/one` will redirect to `site.com/path/two` and `site.com/three?foo=bar`.

However `NavLink` does not work with relative pathnames because it doesn't resolve it's own relative path (which is nontrivial to do). However there are some community packages for this, but I haven't tested them.

Alternatively, and this is what I do, you can get a `match` object from your parent Route (or from the context `router.route.match`) and use it to build your relative `to` in NavLink:

```
<NavLink to={`${match.url}/three`} />
```

this way your component can work independent of it's parent Route(s).

Comment: How does one append to the path then? I don't really understand why <Link to="two" /> should produce site/path/two instead of site/path/one/two ... appending seems like a common use case and if appending was the default behavior it would be easy to get to site/path/two by just doing <Link to="../two" />

Comment: it works the same as a normal `href` on e.g. an HTML `a` tag (at least it tries to, I'm not sure if there is corner cases). If you are at `site/path/one/` (note the trailing slash) `to="two"` will take you to `site/path/one/two`.

Answer (score 17):

It is not supported, but you can easily generate an absolute path:

```
<Link to={this.props.location.pathname + '/path3'}>
```

Comment: Not always working e.g. when the user sends a link to one of your sub pages like I'd send http://diveary.com/path3 to someone and he opens it. The solution above wouldn't work. It would add an additional /path3 to the link...

Comment: Thank you ebrehault...if you're trying to append to the current url, this works like you'd want once you wrap your component in withRouter `import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom`

Answer (score 8):

As per the [API documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#link), links must be absolute:

The `to` property of a `Link` must be a [location descriptor](https://github.com/mjackson/history/blob/master/docs/Glossary.md#locationdescriptor), which is either a string (where it's explicitly stated that

> relative paths are not supported

), or an object with a `pathname` property, which is absolute (by [its definition](https://github.com/mjackson/history/blob/master/docs/Glossary.md#pathname)), too.

There is an [open issue discussing relative links](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/2172), which seems to indicate that relative paths may be supported in future.

Everything said here applies to `react-router` version 2.x and above.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Use the [react-router-relative-links](https://github.com/ryanflorence/react-router-relative-links) library. It was written by Ryan Florence, one of the original authors of react-router.

To use your example, you'd want to use:

```
{ RelativeLink } = require 'react-router-relative-links'
...
<RelativeLink to="./path3">My link text</RelativeLink>
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually react-router support relative links.

Given URL like /clients/invoice/123 the behaviour is:

[image]
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5127

Comment: What about the basename?

Comment: This is highly unpredictable as you never know if the user will use a trailing slash or not

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use `this.props.match.url` because the `match` object has the `url` Object which is the currently loaded path (the page you're currently on).

In the end you can chain `/path1/path2` and build a dynamic relative path like this `this.props.match.url + /path1/path2`

Example:

`<Link to={{ pathname: this.props.match.url + /path1/path2 }}>Path name</Link>`