# Setting Relative Path in React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Is there a way to shorten the path length when routes are passed through components in React Router? For example, in `App.js`:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
  <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
  <PrivateRoute path="/main" component={Main} />
  <Route component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```

And in `Main.js` component:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/main" component={Dashboard} />
    <Route exact path="/main/users" component={Users} />
</Switch>
```

Can I somehow omit adding `/main` before `/main/users` everytime I am in the `Main` component? Can `/main` be set to `/` within that component or do I have to explicitly type the full path every time?

I see discussions talking about something very similar (for example: [Does react-router support relative links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36312453/does-react-router-support-relative-links)) but is there anything for Router **paths** that can be configured? `<Link to="users" />` is said to work but I can't get `<Route path="users" />` to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no "magic" in `react-router` that will automatically inject the current location, but you can do it pretty easily using `this.props.location` that is passed to the component from `<Router />`:

So if you are already at `/main`, you could set your paths to:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path={`${this.props.location.pathname}`} component={Dashboard} />
  <Route exact path={`${this.props.location.pathname}/users`} component={Users} />
</Switch>
```

Which would resolve as:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/main" component={Dashboard} />
  <Route exact path="/main/users" component={Users} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Is there any reason to access the current path as opposed to just hard-coding '/main/users'? Since you're in the Main component anyway?

Comment: @ShaunE.Tobias Accessing the current path instead of hard coding allows for easier code re-use for this component. If the path is hard coded and you change the app structure, you will most likely have to edit the paths. If it is always pulling the current path then you can rearrange the components without having to change any of the internals.

Comment: Fair point, thanks! I hadn't considered the path may be changed. I suppose in implementation you'd do some sort of risk assessment for that scenario since it would prevent future hassle, but could also be unnecessarily convoluted or expensive. Perhaps could be cleaned up by throwing the pathname into a const. Thanks again!

Comment: Note: This answer only applies to `BrowserRouter` and does not work when using `HashRouter`