# Problem with url parameters in React Router

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, url-parameters

I have user's profile and the route is:

`<Route path="/profile/:username" component={UserProfile} />`

The link to go to user profile is on Header, like this:

```
<Link to={`/profile/${props.username}`}>
   <strong>{props.username}</strong> 
</Link>
```

So, profile's url is `localhost:3000/profile/username`

There's another component `UserPosts`.  There's a link on user profile, when clicked, shows user feed. Now I want the url like `locahost:3000/profile/username/posts`

How should my react `Route` component look like? The thing is I'm getting user's posts by `id`.

Backend route is: `/posts/:id`

And, how my `Link` should look like on the `UserProfile` component?

```
<Link to="">
   My Posts
</Link>
```

And, how should I set my routes. Here is my `App.js` currently.

````js
      <div>
          <Router>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route path="/register" component={SignUp} />
              <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
              <PrivateRoute
                path="/post/create"
                component={NewPost}
              />
              <Route path="/profile/:username" component={UserProfile} />
              <Route component={NotFound} />
            </Switch>
          </Router>
        )}
      </div>
    ```
````

Comment: Have you tried `<Link to="posts">`?

Comment: no, I'm asking what should i put in there? `<Link to="posts">` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Did you try it? It's a relative link.

Comment: i want to do it so that the url will be in the UserPosts component  -> `/profile/username/posts`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53711964/setting-relative-path-in-react-router
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36312453/does-react-router-support-relative-links

Comment: If you use `switch` in your router component, write the longer one the first would probably solve your problem.

Comment: I've added my `App.js` file.